# Get parent bean in prototype bean that gets injected

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, design-patterns, slf4j, javabeans

I would like to have a Bean and a SubBean like this:

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class SubBean implements ApplicationContextAware{
  private Object parent;
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx){
    this.parent = doSomeMagicToGetMyParent(ctx);
  }
  public Object getParent(){ 
    return parent; 
  }
}

@Component
public class SomeBean implements InitializingBean{
  @Resource
  private SubBean sub;

  public void afterPropertiesSet(){
    Assert.isTrue(this == sub.getParent());
  }
}
```

The trick I want to achieve is, that the SubBean automagically gets a reference to the Bean it got injected into. Because the scope of the subbean is prototype, it will get injected as a new instance in every parent that wants it to get injected.

My big idea is to exploit this pattern to write a LoggerBean which can be injected into normal beans. The subbean should work just like a SLF4J Logger.

So does anyone know the magic to make this work? :)

---

**EDIT:** I've found a solution to do this with a custom BeanPostProcessor:

```
@Component
public class DependencyInjectionAwareBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
    return bean;
  }
  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
    for (Field f : bean.getClass().getFields()) {
        if (f.getType().isInstance(IDependencyInjectionAware.class)) {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(f);
            try {
                IDependencyInjectionAware diAware = (IDependencyInjectionAware) f.get(bean);
                diAware.injectedInto(bean);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Here is the Interface:

```
public interface IDependencyInjectionAware {
  void injectedInto(Object parent);
}
```

And here a Bean using it:

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class SomeAwareBean implements IDependencyInjectionAware {
  private Object parent;
  public void injectedInto(Object parent){
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  public Object getParent(){
    return parent;
  }
}
```

Here a test with a normal Bean which works perfectly:

```
@Component 
public class UsingBean implements InitializingBean {
  @Resource
  private SomeAwareBean b;
  public void afterPropertiesSet(){
    Assert.notNull(b); //works
    Assert.isTrue(b.getParent() == this); //works
  }
}
```

Though, when using the same with a normal class which gets the depedencies injected via @Configurable, the test fails:

```
@Configurable
public class UsingPlainClass implements InitializingBean {
  @Resource
  private SomeAwareBean b;
  public void afterPropertiesSet(){
    Assert.notNull(b); //works
    Assert.isTrue(b.getParent() == this); //fails because null is returned
  }
}
```

So this seems to have gotten me to another question: Why won't my custom BeanPostProcessor run on a @Configurable classes? Maybe I have to resort to AspectJ afterall...

---

**EDIT:** Just to update the status. I did not implement this afterall because this is overengineering...

Answer (score 0):

I find this simpler:

```
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class SubBean implements ApplicationContextAware{
  private Object parent;
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx){
    ...
  }
  public Object getParent(){ 
    return parent; 
  }
  //ADDED CODE
  public void setParent(Object parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  //END ADDED CODE
}

@Component
public class SomeBean implements InitializingBean{

  private SubBean sub;
  //ADDED CODE
  @Resource
  public void setSub(SubBean sub) {
      this.sub = sub;
      sub.setParent(this);
  }
  //END ADDED CODE

  public void afterPropertiesSet(){
    Assert.isTrue(this == sub.getParent());
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the SomeBean scope? In your application SomeBean is one instance?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed several bugs with the solution given by the original poster:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

public interface DependencyInjectionAware {

void injectedInto(final Object bean, final String beanName);

public static class DependencyInjectionAwareBeanPostProcessor implements
        BeanPostProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger =   Logger.getLogger(DependencyInjectionAwareBeanPostProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean,
            final String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean,
            final String beanName) {
        for (final Field f : bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            logger.info("scanning field " + f.getName() + " of bean " + beanName + " (class= " + bean.getClass() + ")");

            if (DependencyInjectionAware.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(f);
                try {
                    final DependencyInjectionAware diAware = (DependencyInjectionAware) f.get(bean);
                    diAware.injectedInto(bean, beanName);
                } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(e);
                } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
                    ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(e);
                }                   
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

}